# Nested arrays are not supported

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

The new Firebase database Firestore says

> Function DocumentReference.set() called with invalid data. Nested arrays are not supported.

When trying to save the following object:

```
{
  "desc" : "Blala",
  "geojson" : {
    "features" : [ {
      "geometry" : {
        "coordinates" : [ 8.177433013916017, 48.27753810094064 ],
        "type" : "Point"
      },
      "type" : "Feature"
    } ],
    "type" : "FeatureCollection"
  },
  "location" : {
    "lat" : 48.27753810094064,
    "lng" : 8.177433013916017
  },
  "name" : "Wald und Wiesen",
  "owner" : "8a2QQeTG2zRawZJA3tr1oyOAOSF3",
  "prices" : {
    "game" : {
      "Damwild" : 10,
      "Raubwild" : 300,
      "Rehwild" : 250,
      "Schwarzwild" : 40
    },
    "perDay" : 35
  },
  "rules" : "Keine Regeln!",
  "wild" : {
    "desc" : "kein Wild",
    "tags" : [ "Damwild", "Rehwild", "Schwarzwild", "Raubwild" ]
  }
}
```

what exactly is the nested array that firestore is complaining about? I can't find it in the documentation.

If it's the GeoJSON object - how would I save it instead?

Comment: Funny thing is that this doc suggests nested arrays are supported.  Maybe it's a bug in either the code or the doc? https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/manage-data/add-data#data_types

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I'm getting the same error, using CodableFirebase.

Comment: @ProblemsOfSumit, can you confirm if you were able to save the geoJSON. I still get 'FIRInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Nested arrays are not supported'

Answer (score 24, accepted):

UPDATE: This was fixed in Firebase JS SDK 4.6.0. *Directly* nested arrays are still unsupported, but you can now have an array that contains an object that contains an array, etc.

This is a bug in the currently released SDKs.

The backend has the restriction that only directly nested Arrays are unsupported.

In your case you have arrays containing objects containing arrays and the validation logic in the clients is disallowing it when it shouldn't.

There's no public bug tracking this but I'll post back when we have a fix.

Comment: Just to follow up, this has been fixed!

Comment: @MichaelLehenbauer It still doesn't work in the firestore UI on firebase console.

Comment: Still doesn't work for me either on iOS. I get 'FIRInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Nested arrays are not supported'.

Answer (score 11):

You could adapt a serialization function that converts arrays with object types into a map. The keys can be numeric to maintain order.

i.e. 
`{ 1: Object, 2: Object2 ... }`

On deserialization you can get the `Object.values(data);` to put it back into an array to be used client-side.

Answer (score 4):

Can't comment so here it goes: this is fixed in 4.6.0, see release notes: https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js#4.6.0

> Cloud Firestore
>
> FIXED Fixed the validation of nested arrays to allow indirect nesting.

Comment: Checked in 4.6.1 and still see the issue

Comment: It's been almost 5 years, still the same issue.

Comment: I'm still getting this error in 2022 using Firebase 9.1.

Comment: How has this not been fixed yet. This is ridiculous.

Comment: Aug 30 2023, same issue

Comment: 2024 still same issue

Answer (score 2):

Python:

```
# Matrix storage in firestore

def matrix_to_fb_data(matrix):
    return [{'0': row} for row in matrix]

def fb_data_to_matrix(fb_data):
    return [row['0'] for row in fb_data]
```

Firestore doesn't allow 2d arrays, like previous answers have noted, but they allow arrays of maps... of arrays :)

Answer (score 0):

You can alternative insert a document with nested arrays and objects with stringified format; for me, in JavaScript, it's:

```
JSON.stringfiy(someNestedObject);
```

Answer (score 0):

(in case someone finds this question on Google)

I was getting this error in Firebase Admin, but this **[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66317244/4508758)** helped me

Incorrect:

```
import * as admin from "firebase-admin"

document.ref.update({
   "arrayFieldName": admin.firestore.FieldValue.arrayRemove(arrayOfStringToRemove)
});
```

To fix this, I changed to the spread syntax:

```
document.ref.update({
   "arrayFieldName": admin.firestore.FieldValue.arrayRemove(...arrayOfStringToRemove)
});
```