# How to add nested arrays to firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, multidimensional-array, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using vue and firebase/firestore in my project. The data that I want to send to back-end is direct nested arrays like bellow:

```
data() {
  return {
    product: {
      name: null,
      price: null,
      description: null,
      images: [] // this is an array that I am working with
    },
    thumbImgPath: '', // variable to store some path string
    bigImgPath: '',   // variable to store some path string 
    count: 0          // pointer
  }
}
```

So when I press a button to fire the function `saveNewProduct()`, I push an array into the `images` array like so:

```
saveNewProduct() {
  this.product.images.push([this.bigImgPath, this.thumbImgPath])  
}
```

I then get the following error when saving to Firestore:

> Function DocumentReference.set() called with invalid data. Nested arrays are not supported.

After some research online, I found that it's possible to add to the nested array indirectly as described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58693805/11608028) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46593953/nested-arrays-are-not-supported).
So I basically created an array of objects, where each object has a `paths` field and it stores an array.

Below I imitate multiple calls of a `saveNewProduct()` function:

```
saveNewProduct() {
  this.product.images[this.count] = {paths: []};
  this.product.images[this.count].paths.push(['BigPath1', 'smallPath1'])
  this.count++;

  this.product.images[this.count] = {paths: []};
  this.product.images[this.count].paths.push(['BigPath2', 'smallPath2'])
  this.count++;

  this.product.images[this.count] = {paths: []};
  this.product.images[this.count].paths.push(['BigPath3', 'smallPath3'])
  this.count++;   

  console.log('images path are: ', this.product.images)
}
```

The output is:
[image: data structure]

Why are these indirect nested arrays are not working? Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At no point in your data can you have the structure:

```js
field = [
  [val1, val2],
  [val3, val4],
  // ...
]
```

However, you can have:

```js
field = [
  { a: val1, b: val2 },  // "a" and "b" can even be "0" and "1",
  { a: val3, b: val4 },  // but don't do that, it'll only cause headaches
  // ...
]
```

In your original structure, `this.product.images` ends up being:

```js
product.images = [
  ['BigPath1', 'smallPath1'],
  ['BigPath2', 'smallPath2'],
  ['BigPath3', 'smallPath3'],
  // ...
]
```

In your attempt to un-nest the arrays, you end up with:

```js
product.images = [
  { paths: [['BigPath1', 'smallPath1']] }, // <- note single-element array containing array
  { paths: [['BigPath2', 'smallPath2']] },
  { paths: [['BigPath3', 'smallPath3']] },
  // ...
]
```

If you ever see `someArray.push(someOtherArray)` you will run into that error.

To fix the code where you tried to un-nest the array, don't use push on your `paths` object and instead set it directly:

```js
saveNewProduct() {
  this.product.images.push({ paths: ['BigPath1', 'smallPath1'] });
  this.product.images.push({ paths: ['BigPath2', 'smallPath2'] });
  this.product.images.push({ paths: ['BigPath3', 'smallPath3'] });

  console.log('product.images:\n', JSON.stringify(this.product.images, null, 2));
}
```

which produces:

```js
product.images = [
  { paths: ['BigPath1', 'smallPath1'] },
  { paths: ['BigPath2', 'smallPath2'] },
  { paths: ['BigPath3', 'smallPath3'] },
  // ...
]
```

You could also use:

```js
saveNewProduct() {
  this.product.images.push({ image: 'BigPath1', thumb: 'smallPath1' });
  this.product.images.push({ image: 'BigPath2', thumb: 'smallPath2' });
  this.product.images.push({ image: 'BigPath3', thumb: 'smallPath3' });

  console.log('product.images:\n', JSON.stringify(this.product.images, null, 2));
}
```

to produce:

```js
product.images = [
  { image: 'BigPath1', thumb: 'smallPath1' },
  { image: 'BigPath2', thumb: 'smallPath2' },
  { image: 'BigPath3', thumb: 'smallPath3' },
  // ...
]
```