# how would you save and read an array of arrays in firestore?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to save react-seat-picker 
https://github.com/roggervalf/react-seat-picker#readme
data into firestore and read it back.

The one piece of code describing data that should be written/saved to firestore is this:

```
 const rows = [
      [{id: 1, number: 1, isSelected: true, tooltip: 'Reserved by you'}, {id: 2, number: 2, tooltip: 'Cost: 15$'}, null, {id: 3, number: '3', isReserved: true, orientation: 'east', tooltip: 'Reserved by Rogger'}, {id: 4, number: '4', orientation: 'west'}, null, {id: 5, number: 5}, {id: 6, number: 6}],
      [{id: 7, number: 1, isReserved: true, tooltip: 'Reserved by Matthias Nadler'}, {id: 8, number: 2, isReserved: true}, null, {id: 9, number: '3', isReserved: true, orientation: 'east'}, {id: 10, number: '4', orientation: 'west'}, null, {id: 11, number: 5}, {id: 12, number: 6}],
      [{id: 13, number: 1}, {id: 14, number: 2}, null, {id: 15, number: 3, isReserved: true, orientation: 'east'}, {id: 16, number: '4', orientation: 'west'}, null, {id: 17, number: 5}, {id: 18, number: 6}],
      [{id: 19, number: 1, tooltip: 'Cost: 25$'}, {id: 20, number: 2}, null, {id: 21, number: 3, orientation: 'east'}, {id: 22, number: '4', orientation: 'west'}, null, {id: 23, number: 5}, {id: 24, number: 6}],
      [{id: 25, number: 1, isReserved: true}, {id: 26, number: 2, orientation: 'east'}, null, {id: 27, number: '3', isReserved: true}, {id: 28, number: '4', orientation: 'west'}, null,{id: 29, number: 5, tooltip: 'Cost: 11$'}, {id: 30, number: 6, isReserved: true}]
    ]
```

Answer (score 5):

You can stringify your nested array (JSON.stringify(rows)) before storing in firestore and parse it after getting it back.

Answer (score 2):

So far firebase firestore doesn't support nested arrays,you need to change the data structure.Have a look at this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46593953/nested-arrays-are-not-supported)

Comment: Although your suggestion works, nested arrays are a [supported data type](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/manage-data/add-data#data_types) in Firebase Firestore

Comment: Looks like you can only do this through code and not through the Firebase console.

Comment: I don't think it supports nested arrays. If I try to store a nested array through code I get this error: *Cannot convert an array value in an array value*