# How to add nested array into Firebase Firestore?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I want to add a nested array into Firestore but when I tried to Firestore gave the following error

**Unhandled Exception: [cloud_firestore/unknown] Invalid data. Nested arrays are not supported**

Here is JSON format which I want to to add to Firestore:

```
{
        "time": "7:00pm",
        "isSet": false,
        "leds": [
                [0, 0, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 0],
            ]
    }
```

Here is a Model Class Which I was using for passing data

```
class LampModes {
  String name;
  int index;
  List<List<int>> leds;

  LampModes(this.name, this.index, this.leds);

}
```

Is there any way to add a nested array into Firebase Firestore?

Comment: could you please include the way you try so far?

Comment: "Is there any way to add a nested array into firebase firestore?" No, as the error explains.  also checkout: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62094696/13130697

Answer (score 3):

> Is there any way to add a nested array into firebase Firestore?

No, there is not. You cannot add arrays within an existing array type field. What you can do instead, is to create an object (map) that can hold arrays. So this document structure might solve your problem:

```
$docId
  |
  --- leds (map)
       |
       --- $someId: [0, 0, 0, 0]
       |
       --- $someId: [0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Then you can simply read the document, get the `leds` object (map), and iterate the content to get all arrays.

Comment: Hey Alex. thanks for the answer for now we have changed data formats.

Comment: So did my answer help? Can I help you with other information?